# Entity Framework DB updating but DB context not showing updates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, identityserver4

I have the following setup:

- A .NetCore Web API using EF6 for IdentityServer4.
- A unit test project that tests the API.
- DB context is retrieved from the web host's services so *should* be a singleton and the same reference.

With the following steps leading to my issue:

1. Before the test I populate the DB with a resource and some claims.
2. The unit test makes a HTTP DELETE request which results in a claim being deleted. This is visible in the DB as `context.SaveChanges()` is called.
3. The unit test then asserts that the claim has been deleted by using the DB context. This fails due to the context not appearing to update.

The issue is that the EF DB context in the unit test appears to not see the deletion of the claim that the API's DB context made.

Things I have tried:

- Used web host services to retrieve the DB context using `_host.Services.GetServices<ConfigurationDbContext>().First(service => service.GetType() == typeof(ConfigurationDbContext))`.

  - I have checked through running that there is only one ConfigurationDbContext in existence within the services.
- Reloading the unit test's context resource entry using `context.Entry(resource).Reload()`.
- Re-retrieved the context from the web host.

Observations:

- The unit test's context appears to be up-to-date before the deletion.
- Deleting the resource instead of one of its claims seems to be tracked by the unit test's context.
- The DB is as expected so the code under tests appears to be working as expected it is just the unit test's context that is not updating.
- The DB context within the API while stepping through is updating leading to and after the `context.SaveChanges()` call.

Questions:

- Has anyone encountered an issue where a EF DB context does not update?
- Is there a hard refresh method I am missing that would force a re-evaluation of the contexts's state with regards to the referenced DB?
- Is there a cache of some sort that makes the unit test's DB context believe it is up-to-date.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't follow why you're using the singleton pattern here. If you only ever have one instance of your DbContext-derived subclass, in a production web application, you'll end up with multiple threads accessing the same DbContext, which won't work. Each instance of a DbContext represents the changes made to the data by that specific request.

Comment: DbContexts are not supposed to update, since they are not supposed to be so long-lived other transactions interfere (DbContexts are not thread-safe). They are meant to be used in a single unit of work, which might explain your issues.

Comment: Many thanks both for the clarification. Just to confirm my issue is spawning from the fact that I am using the same context and that cannot expect to be updated between the test project and the code under test? In which case I will need to get a new instance of DB context referencing the same DB?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to both Eric J and DevilSuichiro for helping me resolve my issue. The problem was that I should not have been trying to use the same DB context. By retrieving a new DB context instead of trying to reuse the same DB context I was able to verify my test results.

Many thanks again.